# Chrome plugin Dropbox integration

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dropbox

I want to develop some Chrome plugin with the Dropbox support to save user data files in user's Dropbox account.

- User should login Dropbox account
- User data should be stored in JSON format in Dropbox

So, is it possible to realize such integration scenario just using the Dropbox Javascipt API ? OR What will be the steps to achieve such purpose ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to save the data on the Google account that Chrome syncs with, especially for trivial data like settings.

[How to synchronize Chrome extension data on different computers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901024/how-to-synchronize-chrome-extension-data-on-different-computers)

Comment: This solution seems more reasonable. No need for any other cloud storage provider, no need to login etc. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Register an app [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) and you should only need App Folder permissions. Once that is done you have full access to that folder as a filesystem via the [Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core). You can create a file and write it to the user's Dropbox with [writeFile](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#writeFile-instance) and then read it back when necessary. One catch you need to watch out for is the user editing the file and messing some stuff up. If you were to store a useful copy somewhere you can check to see if it has changed and just reject user changes, but something to be aware of. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Dan. My intention is just to save user data into the cloud. Dropbox was just one of the options, however storing with Google Sync seems more reasonable.